# How to organize a list of items within a view based on an item's property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a collection of items. Here's my view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> MyCollection { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{        
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }           
}
```

So my collection has about 200 rows. Multiple rows can have the same vendor name, so there's 5 different vendor names in my collection.

In the view that I'm passing my view model to, I'd like to display the name of each vendor, and under each vendor I want to display a grid of Amount and Tax for that vendor name.

I assume I need to do this within my view, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer to let the view model closely accommodate the view and do as little data manipulation in the view as possible. After all, it is not the view's responsibility to shape data, just to expose them to the user. So I would use

```cs
public class Vendor
{
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VendorInfo> VendorData { get; set; }
}

public class VendorInfo
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}
```

so you can build the UI elements from the vendor names and their details in just one pass.

Comment: This is how I would approach it as well. Don't repeat your data, factor it out. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can employ a 2-step process. In your controller do this:

```
var vendors = MyCollection.Select(myc => myc.VendorName).Distinct();
```

And be sure to pass vendors (along with MyCollection) to your view (or you could just do that on your view--that's up to your own personal preference). Then in the view do this:

```
foreach(var vendor in vendors)
{
  var currentCollection = MyCollection.Select(myc => myc.VendorName.Equals(vendor));
  foreach(MyClass something in currentCollection)
  {
     //Do what you want
  }
}
```

Be sure that when you grab the vendor list in your View (either by the ViewBag or ViewData) to be sure to cast it back to `IEnumerable<string>` (as well as MyCollection to `IEnumerable<MyClass>`), and you should be good to go.